# Kindle fire CM7 barebones: how can I get the home screen into portrait mode?

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, amazon-kindle-fire, orientation

I recently installed [the latest (2/9/2012) build of cyanogen mod 7](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1475054) for my kindle fire. I can't figure out how to get the home screen into a portrait orientation. It defaults to landscape and doesn't respond to the device rotating, although other applications do. I'd appreciate any help.

Unrelated: this rom is awesome!

Comment: Check your settings in `Settings->CyanogenMod Settings->Display` and see if it has the 0 degree and 180 degree orientations enabled? Could be that the ROM author has them turned off by default, perhaps.

Comment: 180 was disabled. I enabled it but the problem persists.

Comment: Hm, only other thing I can think to check off the top of my head would be the launcher settings. I'm assuming it's ADW, so there might be something that controls the layout in `Settings->ADW Settings` (or from a home screen `(Menu Button)->More->ADW Settings`). If there's nothing there then I'm not sure what it could be.

Answer (score 3):

Aha! As edlarerathis commented, you can change this in AWD settings.

```
settings -> ADW settings -> system preferences -> Home orientation
```

change from landscape to auto/sensor.